# Right column of a horizontally-scrollable TableView is not showing completely

Tags: java, javafx, scroll, tableview

I have a TableView with many columns so my table is horizontally-scrollable. If I make cell content left-aligned, it looks as expected:

[image: see screenshot]

After changing it to right-alignment, the end part of the last column becomes covered with a vertical scroll slider. So not all the content is visible:

[image: see screenshot]

Any idea how to fix it?

TableView class:

```
class DataTableView {

private TableView <DataTableModel> dataTable = new TableView<>();

DataTableView(DataObject dataObject)
{
    dataTable.setId("dataTable");
    dataTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    populateTable(dataObject);
}

private void populateTable(DataObject dataObject)
{
    dataTable.getItems().clear();
    dataTable.getColumns().clear();
    dataTable.setPlaceholder(new Label("Loading..."));

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception
        {
            List <String>headerTexts = new ArrayList<>();

            dataObject.getColumnsDataTable().forEach(name ->
                                headerTexts.add(name.getName()+'\n'+name.getUnit()));

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    dataTable.getColumns().add(createIndexColumn());

                    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < headerTexts.size(); columnIndex++)
                    {
                        dataTable.getColumns().add(
                                createColumn(columnIndex, headerTexts.get(columnIndex)));
                    }
                }
            });

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    for(DataTableModel data : prepareDataModel(dataObject))
                    {
                        dataTable.getItems().add(data);
                    }
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}

private TableColumn <DataTableModel,String>  createIndexColumn ()
{
    TableColumn<DataTableModel,String> column = new TableColumn< >("No");

    column.setSortable(false);
    column.setCellFactory(col ->
    {
        TableCell<DataTableModel, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
        cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty())
                .then("")
                .otherwise(cell.indexProperty().add(1).asString()));

        return cell ;
    });
    return column;
}

private TableColumn <DataTableModel, String> createColumn(final int columnIndex, String columnTitle )
{
    TableColumn<DataTableModel, String> column = new TableColumn<>(columnTitle);

    column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getRow().get(columnIndex));

    column.setSortable(false);

    return column;
}

private ObservableList <DataTableModel> prepareDataModel(DataObject dataObject)
{
    ObservableList <DataTableModel> dataTableModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    dataObject.getDataTableData().forEach(row -> dataTableModel.add(new DataTableModel(row)));

    return dataTableModel;
}

public TableView getDataTableView (){
    return dataTable;
}
```

}

CSS for the second screenshot:

```
#dataTable .table-cell {
    -fx-alignment: center-right;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Table model:

```
public class DataTableModel {

    private ObservableList<StringProperty> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public DataTableModel(List <String> data)
    {
        data.forEach(element -> row.add(new SimpleStringProperty(element)));
    }

    public void setRow(ObservableList<StringProperty> row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public ObservableList<StringProperty> getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int size() {
        return row.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it possible setPrefWidth for TableView it can help. If you set any width for column the best way is set sum of columns width.

Comment: What is result? It work?

Comment: Unfortunately, setPrefWidth for TableView doesn't work. The end part of cell content is still hide under scroll slider.

Comment: If it possible attach your code, it will more possibility to help.

Comment: I've added code to the original post.Thank you.

Comment: But can you give me also DataTableModel and DataObject structures i will be easier for me.I will try help, but i can't nothing promise.

Comment: I've added _DataTableModel_. _DataObject_ is an interface; 'dataObject.getDataTableData()' return 'List<List<String>>', in other words, list of rows data.

Comment: I will check this today in night or tomorrow, sorry for that.

Comment: I try it and i don't have this problem, it difficult to say, because maybe it problem from parent container? I can't simulate this situation. Maybe it's not enough space in parent controller? In which container you put this table? You can set prefWidth for parent container.

Comment: @BadVegan, many thanks. Now I found out that it's my issue, not common. The parent container of this table is `Tab`. Both `Tab`(with its `TabPane`) and `TableView` are made dinamically (without `FXML`), because need of their creation difines at runtime. So I have no any idea what exactly `prefWidth` should be set.

Comment: But if you set prefWidth for parent it works good?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The hierarchy tree of my GUI is the following: `AnchorPane` -> `TabPane`(is the last FXML node, other one's are created at runtime; set `prefWidth` of this node doesn't change anything) -> 'Tab' -> `TabPane` -> `Tab` -> `TableView`. Maybe this may help.

Comment: It difficult to reconstruct this situation, you can put here you own code or part of code which I can run and see this problem or put on github. Is to many settings, to create this same problem. I am convinced that is a layout problem.

Answer (score 0):

What JavaFx version do you use? I encountered the same problem while still using JavaFX 8. The issue was resolved when using a newer version (at least with JavaFX 12 or above it is fixed).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30081755)